# Get id from second table from 2 insert queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables(users and subscription) am inserting data to, however, the table subscription gets userid from table users using `$sid = mysqli_insert_id($db)` now I want to get `sid` from table two so that i can pass it to the payment gateway. Here is my snippet

```
 if (isset($_POST['online'])) { 
$_SESSION['lname'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$_SESSION['fname'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$_SESSION['email'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$_SESSION['tele'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['tele']);
$_SESSION['sex'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['sex']);
$_SESSION['address'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$_SESSION['occupation'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['occupation']);
$_SESSION['org'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['org']);
$_SESSION['amount'] = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);



$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, tele, sex, occupation, org) 
                          VALUES('".$_SESSION['fname']."', '".$_SESSION['lname']."', 
                          '".$_SESSION['email']."', 
                         '".$_SESSION['tele']."', '".$_SESSION['sex']."', '".$_SESSION['occupation']."', 
                         '".$_SESSION['org']."')");
$sid = mysqli_insert_id($db);

$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO subscription (userid, amount, event, status, statusmessage) 
                          VALUES('$sid', '".$_SESSION['amount']."','Main Summit', '0', 'Pending Payment by user')");
```

Comment: What is table two, are you referring to the subscription table?

Comment: Just use `mysqli_insert_id($db)` again.

Answer (score 4):

Simply call `mysqli_insert_id` again:

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, tele, sex, occupation, org) 
                          VALUES('".$_SESSION['fname']."', '".$_SESSION['lname']."', 
                          '".$_SESSION['email']."', 
                         '".$_SESSION['tele']."', '".$_SESSION['sex']."', '".$_SESSION['occupation']."', 
                         '".$_SESSION['org']."')");
$userid = mysqli_insert_id($db);

$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO subscription (userid, amount, event, status, statusmessage) 
                          VALUES('$userid', '".$_SESSION['amount']."','Main Summit', '0', 'Pending Payment by user')");

$subscriptionid = mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

I don't know your $db class, but you should [use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating parameters.

Comment: Were in the question do you read that orderid is primary key and auto_incremented of the subscription table?

Comment: orderid isn't anywhere in the code, so I assume the poster is asking about the new subscription record in some way.

Comment: Assuming... do I need to say more?

Comment: Well, this is an honest assumption, seeing as OP didn't specify the primari key in the first `INSERT` either.

Comment: userid is a primary key with auto increment values, same applies to sid